# Difference between editor.html and cf# mode in AEM

Tags: aem-6

I am using AEM 6.5, and cannot get the difference between opening a page in editor.html and cf#.
Sometimes pages is opening fine using editor.html and sometimes the components of page are not getting edited properly using editor.html so I need to use cf#. Please help me get clarity over this.

Answer (score 0):

> cf# -> For accessing the legacy AEM classic editor.
>
> editor.html -> For accessing the AEM Touch UI editor.

Previous the AEM components were built using Ext.js and authored using the legacy AEM classic editor. Currently, the AEM components are being built using Granite UI and authored in Touch UI.

Adobe doesn't recommend to use classic editor. And, this editor is unavailable in AEM as Cloud Service.